# Joomla 3, Helix 3- shaper template - Mobile version of site is "out of center"

Tags: mobile, joomla, helix

I designed a new site simple enough, with a top slider and menus. It seems that when I view the site via PC all is fine and in place.

When I view the site from a mobile phone (Android) it seems that the top slider is not centered.

The website address is: http://www.donoussa.gr

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a styling conflict where Bootstrap applies the following CSS:

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

I suggest overriding the CSS as follows:

```
.row {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
}
```

You can override the CSS in Helix as per https://joomla.stackexchange.com/a/14219/120 or similar.

Comment: But can i make it fit the edges of the white frame ??

Comment: I have amended the answer. Feel free to upvote if this is useful!

Comment: The previous answer before the "fix" was ok for mobile version of the site but then it creates the same problem on the pc browser version of the site.